# Queue Linux Can't Write

Tags: c, linux

I got problem in my code for process code:

```
FILE *fp;
int     i, 
    counter;    // Liczba liter w wiadomosci
wchar_t buffer[1024], *line;
struct MsgStructure WB; // Write Buffor
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL.UTF-8");

while(run)
{
    fp = fopen(FIFO, "r");
    fwide(fp, 1);
    while ((line = fgetws(buffer, sizeof buffer / sizeof buffer[0], fp)) != NULL) 
    {
          counter = 0;
          for (i = 0; line[i] != L'\0'; i++)
              if (iswalpha(line[i]))
                 counter++;

          WB.Msg = counter;

          if ((WriteToQueue( qid, &WB )) == -1)     
          {
               perror("Error\n");
          }

    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

My program read from FIFO file then count the amount of letters and then i want to write it to queue but i got an error that i can't write to queue because "Wrong argument"

My structure:

```
struct MsgStructure { 
    long int MsgType; 
    int Msg; 
};
```

WriteToQueue is a simple function:

```
int WriteToQueue( int qid, struct MsgStructure *qbuf ){
    int result, BufSize;

    BufSize = sizeof(struct MsgStructure) - sizeof(long);        
    result = msgsnd( qid, qbuf, BufSize, 0);
      return(result);
}
```

My message type is int and counter is int too. I don't know why this isn't work. Maybe this is problem with setlocale ??
Queue is creating in other process.

Comment: by "Wrong argument" you mean EINVAL (aka Invalid argument)?

Comment: Did you do get `qid` using `msgget()` successfully?

Comment: yes the queue was create successfully. Whole problem appears when i make counting letters with setlocale() fuction and when i get fgets() for reading from file.

Comment: Well, EINVAL is set when either `qid` has an invalid value; `mtype` is non-positive, or `BufSize` is <0 or >MSGMAX.  I ruled out the latter, you ruled out the former, so it must be that `MsgType` in your `qbuf` has a non-positive value (i.e. 0 or negative)

Comment: in my qbuf: mtype has value 0, BufSize is always > 0 and < MSGMAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

```
   EINVAL Invalid msqid value, or nonpositive mtype value,
          or invalid msgsz value (less than 0 or greater than
          the system value MSGMAX).
```

The former has been ruled out and the latter is obviously not true, i.e. `BufSize` being `sizeof(int)` in the example code.

Leaves `mtype<=0`.  From the man page:

```
   The msgp argument is a pointer to caller-defined
   structure of the following general form:

       struct msgbuf {
           long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
           char mtext[1];    /* message data */
       };
```

This is in accordance to `msgrcv()` whose `msgtyp` argument, if 0, has a special meaning.

Solution is to set `MsgType` in `struct MsgStructure` to something greater than 0.

Comment: extra question: this program is for counting letters but when i have line like: qwertqq \00 azerty   it only count to 7 but should to 13. How can i fix that ?

Comment: Don't use `fgetws` in that case, read the buffer yourself (using `read()`), check for the newline character using `memchr()`, which allows to have `\0`s in your string, then process the chunk from the start of the buffer till what `memchr()` gives you, set the buffer to past the newline character and start over again.  Summary: do manual line chunking

Comment: is there any chance for an example ?

Comment: Raise a new question for that.